# Top margin issue in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, margin

I have a problem with the margin in IE.
I have an image placed in div. I made all the margins set to 0.
But still the top margin is showing a little. I don't want to set the

margin-top to a negative value. This happens only in Ie because in firefox
its positioned perfectly.

Do you have workaround for this?
Here's my attritbutes to div:

```
.placeImage {
visibility:visible;
overflow:auto;
height:400px;
background-image: url(image.jpg); 
background-repeat: no-repeat ;
background-position:left;
}
```

I read that I can put margin:0 in the body tag so:

```
<body style="margin-top:0; margin-left:0;">
```

The left margin is okay but the top still shows a little space at the back..
Help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting:

```
body
{
    padding:0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Feel free to look at this jsFiddle here demonstrating this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lrume/2/

Comment: this one made it too:  <style type="text/css">
                       * {margin:0; padding:0;}

Comment: @tinks I wouldn't do that.  That will make all elements have no margin or padding.

Comment: I also would like to confirm that IE and firefox treats the margins differently, right?

Comment: @tinks I seem to remember IE acting weird and all the other browsers working as expected.  I don't have any actual proof though.

Comment: Made the page successful in terms of giving what I wanted it to look like! Because if i set the margins and padding in the body only, the top space was reduced only. But when i included the universal setting for margin it eliminated the space completely.

Comment: @tinks Odd, well, did my answer help at all?  If so, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @tinks - don't use the star selector `* {...}` because it can cause a big processing overhead for some browsers. I recommend using one of the established reset stylesheets (see my answer for more info)

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this padding issue is all well and good, but there are a number of other little cross-browser quirks in the default stylesheets which may trip you up.

What you really need to do is use a 'reset' stylesheet to iron out all those quirks in one go.

This is quite a common issue, and a number of people have written reset stylesheets. I use [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), but this does a lot more than just resetting stylesheets, so rather than recommend a specific one, I'll point you to this discussion elsewhere on Stackoverflow that covers most of the options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Hope that helps